# Selenium Python - How to click a span with given text

Tags: python, selenium

I need to click a row in a table, I'm unable to do so. To be more specific, I need to click ALL_USA, you can see in the code below.
My HTML code is below:

```
<div id="table" arid="1" arwindowid="0" style="height: 299px; width: 638px;">
 <div class="TableHdr" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; width: 638px;">
  <div class="TableInner" style="top: 0px; height: 277px; width: 638px;">
   <div class="BaseTableOuter" draghandler="BaseTable_DragHandler" style="height: 275px; width: 636px;">
    <div class="BaseTableColHeaders" style="width: 636px; left: 0px;">
     <div class="BaseTableInner" style="top: 16px; height: 259px; width: 636px;  overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
      <table id="T1" class="BaseTable" title="" style="width: 2px;">
   <colgroup cols="1">
  <tbody>
        <tr class="hiddentablehdr">
        <tr class="" tabindex="0" arrow="0">
        <tr tabindex="0" arrow="1">
        <tr tabindex="0" arrow="2">
        <tr tabindex="0" arrow="3">
        <tr class="SelPrimary" tabindex="0" arrow="4">
        <td class="BaseTableCellOdd BaseTableCellOddColor BaseTableStaticText" "scope="row" style="width: 636px;">
          <nobr class="dp " style="text-align: left; width: 636px;">
             <span style="padding: 1px 4px;float:left;">ALL_USA</span>
         </nobr>
     </td>
  </tr>
 <tr tabindex="0" arrow="5">
```

Comment: *I'm unable to do so...* Show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ALL_USA` is subject to change, then you can use:

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.BaseTable tr.SelPrimary td span").click();`

Comment: Thanks. It partially worked. I'm able to click the element, but it's clicking the second in the list

Comment: Try :first-child Selector. `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("table.BaseTable tr.SelPrimary td > span:first-child").click()`

Comment: Hi, it is clicking same element everytime. looks like this table is dynamically generated. <table id="T1" class="BaseTable" title="" style="width: 2px;">
<colgroup cols="1">
<tbody>
<tr class="hiddentablehdr">
<tr class="" tabindex="0" arrow="0">
<tr class="SelPrimary" tabindex="0" arrow="1">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="2">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="3">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="4">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="5">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="6">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="7">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="8">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="9">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="10">
<tr tabindex="0" arrow="11">

Answer (score 3):

You can use an xpath to target the span text:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='ALL_USA']").click();
```